# Any information on MCMErrorDomain error 44?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am running into "MCMErrorDomain error 44" about 50% of the time on app.launch() when loading a container to my app. I have no idea what is the cause and I can't find any information about this error.

This is the code I am using to load container to the app.

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func loadAppData(appDataPath: String) {
        let loaderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
        let bundleUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: appDataPath, relativeTo: loaderUrl).appendingPathExtension("xcappdata")
        let contentsURL = bundleUrl.appendingPathComponent("AppData")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        let enumerator = fileManager.enumerator(at: contentsURL,
                                                includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],
                                                options: [],
                                                //swiftlint:disable:next force_unwrapping
                                                errorHandler: nil)!
        //swiftlint:disable:next force_unwrapping
        let destinationRoot = fileManager.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!.deletingLastPathComponent()
        let test =  fileManager.enumerator(at: destinationRoot,
                                           includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey],
                                           options: [],
                                           //swiftlint:disable:next force_unwrapping
                                           errorHandler: nil)!

        while let lol = test.nextObject() as? URL {
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: lol)
            } catch {
                print("✌️ \(error)")
            }
        }

        print("✌️ \(destinationRoot)")
        let sourceRoot = contentsURL.standardizedFileURL.path
        while let sourceUrl = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL {
            guard let resourceValues = try? sourceUrl.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]),
                let isDirectory = resourceValues.isDirectory,
                !isDirectory else {
                    continue
            }
            let path = sourceUrl.standardizedFileURL.path.replacingOccurrences(of: sourceRoot, with: "")
            let destinationURL = destinationRoot.appendingPathComponent(path)
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURL.deletingLastPathComponent(),
                                                withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                attributes: nil)

                try fileManager.copyItem(at: sourceUrl,
                                         to: destinationURL)
            } catch {
                print("✌️ \(error)")
                do {
                    _ = try fileManager.replaceItemAt(destinationURL, withItemAt: sourceUrl)
                } catch {
                    print("✌️ \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        print("done")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you step through the function, which line produces the error?

Comment: Xcode has a feature of preloading application data for tests. Unfortunately it has been broken since 2016: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6120415860621312 Still not working with Xcode 11.5 in 2020. Please file feedback to Apple Developer Program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `MCMErrorDomain` is frustrating, as it not documented by Apple.

When I encounter it, the full description reads:

> The test runner encountered an error (Failed to install or launch the
>   test runner. (Underlying error: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (MCMErrorDomain error 44.)))

The workaround I found is to delete the app from simulator and re-run the test.

So far, here is what I am learning about this particular error:

1. it looks as it is coming from `MobileContainerManager.framework`
2. often caused by interrupting a running test on simulator.
3. once it happens the simulator often in permanently "damaged" state until app is deleted.
4. only happens for Application tests, that require host app, never for Logic tests.
5. happens only at the beginning of a test suite
6. often caused by Xcode Bot trying to use the same simulator that Xcode is already using.

Framework Location:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileContainerManager.framework`

shows entries for `MCMErrorDomain` in `MobileContainerManager` binary and in `containermanagerd`

Comment: Filed Feedback to Apple: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4997213897883648
with steps to reproduce.

Please submit simular feedback to Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/
to up vote the issue.